# getting the Active Directory objectGUID of a domain joined windows computer

Tags: active-directory

In Microsoft Active Directory, each registered computer has an `objectGUID` field.

[image]

Is this data stored locally on the domain-joined computer? 
I'm interested in retrieving the `objectGUID` value by locally running a command or calling an API on this Windows computer.

Possible? How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this data stored locally on the domain-joined computer?

No it is not.

> I'm interested in retrieving the objectGUID value by locally running a command or calling an API on this Windows computer.

If you know the administrator password of a domain admin account, you can use Powershell to remote query this information. This can also be run from the domain controller locally.

If you need to have something unique, that is available locally, you should use the computername. This cannot be the same in a network, especially not when the computers are domain joined, and these usually don't change either.

If you really need something unique locally that won't ever change, consider the following command on powershell:

```
Get-ComputerInfo -property WindowsProductID
```

Do note, the Get-ComputerInfo queries a lot of information from the computer, and as such this command takes a while to run. It probably also requires local administrative rights, so you most likely need to run powershell as administrator.

The ComputerName does not require administrative rights though.